# Tracking tweets from webpage with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, twitter, analytics, google-analytics-api

According to [Google Analytic's documentation on social tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html), I'm supposed to run this code to notify GA when there's been a tweet:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
  if (event) {
    var targetUrl;
    if (event.target && event.target.nodeName == 'IFRAME') {
      targetUrl = extractParamFromUri(event.target.src, 'url');
    }
    _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'twitter', 'tweet', targetUrl]);
  }
});
```

However, I get an error stating `twttr` is not defined.  How do I get notified of a tweet from my tweet button on my site so that I can track it?

Comment: Are you defining `extractParamFromUri`? that's a custom function they provide, not a native one.

Comment: Yes I did define that, I did get this working somehow.  For some reason I was getting an error about `twttr` not being defined, but that error went away and it's all working now...  Maybe a caching issue of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify you have included the correct code for the twitter button?[describe here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html#twitter)

After that open up the console on firebug and write twttr and hit enter. It should return the twttr Object.

[image]

If not verify that your tracking code is below the twitter include script (the one that actually creates the twttr Object)

HTH

Comment: I do have the correct code for the twitter button as the twitter button looks and functions properly.  But if I write twttr in Firebug's or Chrome's console, it says twttr is not defined.  Strange though I just checked now and I do in fact get an object back!

Comment: It's all working now thanks.  I guess some kind of caching issue, but the webpage is able to see the twttr variable and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading the Twitter API asynchronously, you need to wrap the `twttr.events` functions inside the following:

```
twttr.ready(function(twttr) {

});
```

This way it will wait for the async resources to finish loading before trying to access them.
 You can see more here:

[Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events#waiting-for-asynchronous-resources)

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap a check for the type of the twttr object then that will fix it:

```
// Twitter API 'Tweet' button tracking
    if (typeof(twttr) != 'undefined') {
        twttr.events.bind('click', function(event) {        
            _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'twitter', 'tweet', document.location.href, location.pathname]);

        });     
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping your code in typeof(twttr) != 'undefined' will mean that twttr.events.bind will never be reached since twttr is undefined. So don't do this.